# How do I debug and inspect things that change on response to mouseclicks or focus changes?

Tags: javascript, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I'm currently toying around with some autocomplete form fields, and am finding it very hard to inspect the generated drop down items. As soon as I click on the "inspect element" button or try to right click on the dropdowns, the original autocomplete input runs an onclick event (or something that triggers on a focus change) and hides, deletes or otherwise modifies the element I was trying to inspect.

Is there a way to work with the debugger so that the mouseclicks and other commands I give to it don't get intercepted by the script I'm trying to debug?

I currently have this kind of problem on both Firebug and on Chrome's inspector. The only solution I can think right now would be setting some smart breakpoints inside the appropriate event handlers but that is hard to do if I don't know what event handlers to look for or where they are hidden in the original code...

Comment: I’m experiencing the same problem so I created [crbug.com/160510](http://crbug.com/160510)

Answer (score 5):

You could set a breakpoint and inspect after it is triggered, I have noticed that freezes the DOM.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, setting breakpoints is anoying if I have to do that multiple times or if I don't know the structure of the code I am debugging. Is there a more direct way to freeze the DOM?

Comment: @missingno you could, for example, attach a dummy event handler to all elements on hover, then set a breakpoint inside it. It would be annoying having to continue execution each time, but breakpoints can be conditional.

Comment: It freezes the DOM but also disables right-click, so you can't use "Inspect Element". You can still explore in Elements view if you know what you're looking for, though. At least that way you can see it highlighted when you hover over it in Elements, which you can't really do live for things that disappear when you move the mouse away from them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use breakpoints.  As far as tracking down what's happening where, Chrome's "Call Stack" window can be very helpful.

Cheers

Comment: Setting breakpoints is hard to do though if I didn't write the script and don't know where to put the breakpoints in. Is there a way to just pause script execution as a whole without the breakpoints?

Comment: If you haven't used them, read up on Chrome's `XHR Breakpoints` and `Event Listener Breakpoints`, you may be able to utilize either/both...it just depends on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

In Firebug you have a `Break on next` item in `Script` panel. Since Firebug  1.10, there's a [keyboard shortcut](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Keyboard_and_Mouse_Shortcuts#Global) for this: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> on Windows (it works even if focus is in the page, not in Firebug).

You'll probably need to have `Script` panel focused in Firebug since this is a shared shortcut for `Break on...` which differs in each panel.

It generally freezes the DOM although it's not 100% reliable.

It's also not ideal because it will stop at any JavaScript execution, and will not be helpful if there is some aggressive polling in the background, or global capturing of keyboard events. Anyway it's still better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome pauses Javascript execution on `F8`; it took a bit of repetition but pressing `F8` at the right time prevented JS from defocusing the element.

Comment: This worked surprisingly well when dealing with a result list that disappears from the DOM and you don't have control over 1. finding the compiled JS and 2. adding additional inline JS

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problem selecting the element, you can try <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> on Mac to select the element without right clicking it.

If its DOM manipulation problem, you might try to force state on the input element by right clicking on the element in the Elements panel and set force state to focus.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the docked DevTools first (the undocked approach will not work due to the OS limitations.)
2. Once the autocomplete box is displayed, right-click it and select "Inspect Element" in the context menu. The focus will move to the DevTools but the autocomplete box will still be shown (this worked for me on Linux, tip-of-tree Chromium, M25. Your mileage may vary.)

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Utility to freeze actual DOM state, for example dropdown menu
 */
function easyBreak() {
    function doBreak() {
        // put breakpoint here to freeze actual dom and write to console easyBreak()
        // you have 3 seconds to get to desired state
        var a = 0;
    }

    window.setTimeout(doBreak, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **DOM breakpoints**.

I'm having a similar case here : I want to inspect dropdown items that only show when the input has focus.

On Chrome, I right-click on the parent element and choose `Break on` > `Subtree modifications`.
It will pause - like it does with JS breakpoints - anytime the DOM changes within that parent. You can then inspect the children while the DOM is frozen.